# Улучшение страницы справки по привилегии "Проверенный участник"

Tags: обсуждение, справка, формулировка

В статье [Справка > Привилегии > Проверенный участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) написано:

> **Кто считается проверенным пользователем?**
>
> Проверенным пользователям разрешено выполнять ответственные действия, в том числе...

На [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) в соответствующем разделе написано так:

> **What are trusted users?**
>
> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including...

Дословный перевод, конечно, верный, но, как мне кажется, на вопрос "кто считается *кем-либо*" отвечать "*кому-либо* разрешено..." не совсем лексически корректно и согласованно.

Возможно, было бы правильнее расширить перевод для его русификации, например как-то так: *"Проверенным считается пользователь, которому разрешено..."*? Ну или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: Ему разрешено потому что он проверенный, а у тебя получается наоборот.

Comment: @Qwertiy, именно к этому я и веду. Разве не звучит несогласованно: "Кто считается проверенным пользователем? - Ему разрешено вот это, вот это и вот это, потому что он проверенный."?

Comment: Ну так тогда заголовок надо менять, а не текст?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не совсем верный пример привел. Акцент здесь больше на самой несогласованности, чем на конкретном примере. И соглашусь, логичнее наверное было бы поменять заголовок, т.к. из описания привилегии и так понятно, кто такой проверенный пользователь. Ни к чему это еще раз описывать.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы предложил поменять сам заголовок, "Кто считается проверенным пользователем?" на что-нить вроде:

> Какими привилегиями обладает проверенный участник?